# Merge two videos side by side and top bottom like TikTok Duet does

Tags: ios, swift, merge, tiktok

I want to merge two videos in similar ways TikTok does. I saw many solutions on Stackoverflow but nothing works for me.
The video should place Side by Side and Top bottom ways.
Please take a look at the attached image.
On the left side, One video is on top and the second is on the bottom but fills the full-screen width and height.
Similarly, on the right side of the image, Both videos are side by side, filling the required screen width and height equally.

[image]

I am using two different functions for merging videos.

```
func mergeVideosTopBottom(videoURL1: URL, videoURL2: URL, outputURL: URL, completion: @escaping (Bool, Error?) -> Void) {
    let asset1 = AVAsset(url: videoURL1)
    let asset2 = AVAsset(url: videoURL2)
    
    guard let videoTrack1 = asset1.tracks(withMediaType: .video).first,
          let videoTrack2 = asset2.tracks(withMediaType: .video).first else {
        completion(false, nil)
        return
    }
    
    let composition = AVMutableComposition()
    
    guard let compositionTrack1 = composition.addMutableTrack(withMediaType: .video, preferredTrackID: kCMPersistentTrackID_Invalid),
          let compositionTrack2 = composition.addMutableTrack(withMediaType: .video, preferredTrackID: kCMPersistentTrackID_Invalid) else {
        completion(false, nil)
        return
    }
    
    try? compositionTrack1.insertTimeRange(CMTimeRange(start: .zero, duration: asset1.duration), of: videoTrack1, at: .zero)
    try? compositionTrack2.insertTimeRange(CMTimeRange(start: .zero, duration: asset2.duration), of: videoTrack2, at: .zero)
    
    let instruction = AVMutableVideoCompositionInstruction()
    instruction.timeRange = CMTimeRange(start: .zero, duration: CMTimeMaximum(asset1.duration, asset2.duration))
    
    let transformer1 = AVMutableVideoCompositionLayerInstruction(assetTrack: compositionTrack1)
    let transformer2 = AVMutableVideoCompositionLayerInstruction(assetTrack: compositionTrack2)
    
    let transform1 = videoTrack1.preferredTransform
    let transform2 = videoTrack2.preferredTransform
    
    transformer1.setTransform(transform1, at: .zero)
    transformer2.setTransform(transform2, at: .zero)
    
    let videoComposition = AVMutableVideoComposition()
    videoComposition.instructions = [instruction]
    videoComposition.frameDuration = CMTime(value: 1, timescale: 30) // Set desired frame rate
    
    // Calculate the output video size
    let videoSize = CGSize(width: max(videoTrack1.naturalSize.width, videoTrack2.naturalSize.width),
                           height: videoTrack1.naturalSize.height + videoTrack2.naturalSize.height)
    videoComposition.renderSize = videoSize
    
    instruction.layerInstructions = [transformer1, transformer2]
    
    guard let exporter = AVAssetExportSession(asset: composition, presetName: AVAssetExportPresetHighestQuality) else {
        completion(false, nil)
        return
    }
    
    exporter.outputURL = outputURL
    exporter.outputFileType = .mp4
    exporter.shouldOptimizeForNetworkUse = true
    exporter.videoComposition = videoComposition
    
    exporter.exportAsynchronously {
        switch exporter.status {
        case .completed:
            print("Completed......")
            DispatchQueue.main.async {
                guard let url = exporter.outputURL else {return}
                let objAVPlayerVC = AVPlayerViewController()
                  objAVPlayerVC.player = AVPlayer(url: url)
                  self.present(objAVPlayerVC, animated: true, completion: {() -> Void in
                      objAVPlayerVC.player?.play()
                  })
            }
        case .failed:
            print("Failed......")
        case .cancelled:
            print("Cancelled......")
        default:
            break
        }
    }
}
```

And the second function is

```
 func mergeVideosSideBySide(videoURL1: URL, videoURL2: URL, outputURL: URL, completion: @escaping (Bool, Error?) -> Void) {
    let asset1 = AVAsset(url: videoURL1)
    let asset2 = AVAsset(url: videoURL2)
    
    guard let videoTrack1 = asset1.tracks(withMediaType: .video).first,
          let videoTrack2 = asset2.tracks(withMediaType: .video).first else {
        completion(false, nil)
        return
    }
    
    let composition = AVMutableComposition()
    
    guard let compositionTrack1 = composition.addMutableTrack(withMediaType: .video, preferredTrackID: kCMPersistentTrackID_Invalid),
          let compositionTrack2 = composition.addMutableTrack(withMediaType: .video, preferredTrackID: kCMPersistentTrackID_Invalid) else {
        completion(false, nil)
        return
    }
    
    try? compositionTrack1.insertTimeRange(CMTimeRange(start: .zero, duration: asset1.duration), of: videoTrack1, at: .zero)
    try? compositionTrack2.insertTimeRange(CMTimeRange(start: .zero, duration: asset2.duration), of: videoTrack2, at: .zero)
    
    let instruction = AVMutableVideoCompositionInstruction()
    instruction.timeRange = CMTimeRange(start: .zero, duration: CMTimeMaximum(asset1.duration, asset2.duration))
    
    let transformer1 = AVMutableVideoCompositionLayerInstruction(assetTrack: compositionTrack1)
    let transformer2 = AVMutableVideoCompositionLayerInstruction(assetTrack: compositionTrack2)
    
    let transform1 = videoTrack1.preferredTransform
    let transform2 = videoTrack2.preferredTransform
    
    transformer1.setTransform(transform1, at: .zero)
    transformer2.setTransform(transform2, at: .zero)
    
    let videoComposition = AVMutableVideoComposition()
    videoComposition.instructions = [instruction]
    videoComposition.frameDuration = CMTime(value: 1, timescale: 30) // Set desired frame rate
    
    // Calculate the output video size
    let videoSize = CGSize(width: videoTrack1.naturalSize.width + videoTrack2.naturalSize.width,
                           height: max(videoTrack1.naturalSize.height, videoTrack2.naturalSize.height))
    videoComposition.renderSize = videoSize
    
    instruction.layerInstructions = [transformer1, transformer2]
    
    guard let exporter = AVAssetExportSession(asset: composition, presetName: AVAssetExportPresetHighestQuality) else {
        completion(false, nil)
        return
    }
    
    exporter.outputURL = outputURL
    exporter.outputFileType = .mp4
    exporter.shouldOptimizeForNetworkUse = true
    exporter.videoComposition = videoComposition
    
    exporter.exportAsynchronously {
        switch exporter.status {
        case .completed:
            print("Completed......")
            DispatchQueue.main.async {
                guard let url = exporter.outputURL else {return}
                let objAVPlayerVC = AVPlayerViewController()
                  objAVPlayerVC.player = AVPlayer(url: url)
                  self.present(objAVPlayerVC, animated: true, completion: {() -> Void in
                      objAVPlayerVC.player?.play()
                  })
            }
        case .failed:
            print("Failed......")
        case .cancelled:
            print("Cancelled......")
        default:
            break
        }
    }
}
```

But in the output video, only one video is available and it will not fill out the screen.

I Also tried this library [DPVideoMerger](https://github.com/Datt1994/DPVideoMerger-Swift)
But this library merged video with different

Any help will be appreciated.

Comment: In the TikTop app, how do you know the merging is done in code and not in a video editing software? Maybe it's just one video that is played in the app.

Comment: @JoakimDanielson I am not sure. But i want the same behaviour in my application like the TikTok has.

Comment: @IrfanSaeed - if you want a **Portrait** full-screen video to take up only one-half of the screen width, but the full screen height, you must either "stretch" it or "crop" it. Your `mergeVideosSideBySide` function appears to generate a video that is "full height" but *double* the width.

Answer (score 0):

You almost there! Your code just overlapping two video tracks, so the last track added show when exported. We need to add some transform on it to seperate it.

All you need to do is just add extra transform to the  transformer.setTransform to move the first video track to left/top half of screen, and second video track to right/bottom half of screen.

Let’s talk about left and right case.

NOTE: It may not be the final result you wanted, but we are on the right track.

```
let transform1 = videoTrack1.preferredTransform
let transform2 = videoTrack2.preferredTransform

let halfWidth = 1080/2   // change for real size
transform1.scaledBy(x: 0.5, y: 0.5)
transform1.translatedBy(x: 0, y: 0) // keep in left half of screen

transform2.scaledBy(x: 0.5, y: 0.5)
transform2.translatedBy(x: halfWidth, y: 0) // move to right half of screen

transformer1.setTransform(transform1, at: .zero)
transformer2.setTransform(transform2, at: .zero)
```